# For loop always prints last iteration in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
for sentence in reviewlist:
    print(sentence)
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
    for key in sorted(scores):
         print('{0}: {1}, '.format(key, scores[key]), end='')
```

this code prints all iteration of the sentences but the score only prints for the last iteration. Please help.

Comment: I tried:
scores = {'a':10,'d':2,'b':5}
for key in sorted(scores): 
    print('{0}: {1}, '.format(key, scores[key]), end='')

Output is: a: 10, b: 5, d: 2,   this is the output you want?

Comment: first thanks for your time but as i am doing sentiment analysis and for every sentence it should print the scores. 
the sentences are
It is an amazing movie
This is a dull movie. I would never recommend it to anyone.
The cinematography is pretty great in this movie 
The direction was terrible and the story was all over the place

Comment: Are you sure that there is more than 1 score for each sentence? Can you provide more input data in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Given your `end=''` argument to print, you will never print a newline except at `print(sentence)`, so you should expect your previous scores and current sentence to be printed on the same line.

I would suggest trying some debugging to see what values you are getting:

```
for sentence in reviewlist:
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
    print(sentence, scores)  # make sure that scores isn't empty
    for key in sorted(scores):
         print('{0}: {1}, '.format(key, scores[key]), end='')
    print()  # actually get a newline between sentences
```

If `scores` comes back as an empty dictionary, then that might be the issue. If that doesn't help, update your question with more detail about your inputs and the values of scores returned by the sid function.